# Laravel 4 redirecting inputs back to page after validation fail

Tags: javascript, validation, laravel

I have 4 fields that will be dynamically created by users.

```
<div class="controls" id="exchange-fields">
           <p>
            <div id='exchange_div'>
            <div class="input-append" id='currency_div1'>
            {{ Form::select('currency_id[]', $currencies, null, array('name'=>'currency_id', 'id'=>'currency_id', 'value'=>'Input::old("currency_id")[0]' )) }} 
            </div>

            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <div class="input-prepend" id='actual_div1'>
            <span class="add-on">Actual</span>
            {{ Form::text('exchange_rate[]', null, array('class'=>'input-medium rate', 'maxlength'=>10, 'id'=>'exchange_rate', 'value'=>'Input::old("exchange_rate")[0]' )) }}
            </div>

            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <div class="input-append" id='markup_div1'>
            {{ Form::text('exchange_rate_markup[]', null, array('class'=>'input-mini yellow rate', 'maxlength'=>4, 'id'=>'exchange_rate_markup', 'value'=>'Input::old("exchange_rate_markup")[0]' )) }}<span class="add-on">%</span> 
            </div>

            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <div class="input-prepend" id='rate_div1'>
            <span class="add-on">Marked-up</span>
            {{ Form::text('after_markup_rate[]', null, array('class'=>'input-medium yellow', 'maxlength'=>10, 'id'=>'after_markup_rate', 'value'=>'Input::old("after_markup_rate")[0]' )) }}
            </div>


        </div>
        </div>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <div class="controls">
                 <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="addScnt" value="Add">

            </div>
```

I uses javascript to populate these fields dynamically.

```
var scntDiv = $('#exchange-fields');
    var i = $('#exchange-fields p').size() + 1;


    $('#addScnt').click(function() {        

     $(scntDiv).append('<p>');   
     $("#exchange_div").clone().attr("id",'exchange_div_'+ i).appendTo(scntDiv); 

//Append the remove button
    $($('#exchange_div_'+ i)).append('<input class="btn btn-primary" name="remove" type="button" id="remScnt" value="Remove">');
    i++;

    });
```

This is working perfectly until I POST these values to my controller and if validation fails.
How do I re populate those fields with the old input that are dynamically populated in my view file?

I use return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($e->getErrors()); to redirect after validation fail to repopulate those fields. But because these 4 fields only accept string values and the input returning back are in array so I am unable to repopulate these 4 fields after validation fails.

Any good ways to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using `Input::old("exchange_rate_markup.0")` instead of `Input::old("exchange_rate_markup")[0]` ?

Comment: Does not work as well

Answer (score 3):

@a7omiton Instead of returning all inputs. I use Input::except(array) to return the rest of the fields which are not array.

While redirecting back I use an additional with() to return the array of fields like how you render your view when you load the page initially.

```
// If validation fails, ignore those exchange rate fields 
//because they are in array not string
$input = Input::except([
    'currency_id', 
    'exchange_rate', 
    'exchange_rate_markup', 
    'after_markup_rate'
]);
// return normally as separate array and it will store in session
return Redirect::back()
    ->withInput($input)
    ->withErrors($e->getErrors())
    ->with('exchange_rate', Input::get('exchange_rate'))
    ->with('currency_id', Input::get('currency_id'))
    ->with('exchange_rate_markup', Input::get('exchange_rate_markup'))
    ->with('after_markup_rate', Input::get('after_markup_rate'));
```

Comment: How could I access `exchange_rate` in the view I just redirected back to?

Answer (score 0):

Don't set the value of the input fields in the HTML. Laravel will do this automatically when validation fails.

The second argument in `Form::text` is the value. Setting this to null will allow Laravel to automatically populate it.

Comment: Dear Bradley, I think you misunderstood my qns. This works when the fields are statically created on the html. My qns now is for those dynamically created fields(created by Javascript), how do I automatically populate back when validation fails. Anyway, I have solved this problem. Thanks

Comment: Ah I see , sorry misunderstood.

Comment: @Eain curious to know how you solved the problem, I'm working on a solution for the same issue

Answer (score 0):

laravel will autopopulate the form fields.
Just put second parameter with Input::old('column_name').

```
{{ Form::text('name', Input::old('name'), array('class' => 'span4','placeholder' => 'name')) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Though it is an old post, this will help some one land here looking for the solution.

You can get all the input variable in the view after a redirection by adding this code in your laravel view,

```
print_r(app('request')->old());
```

you can assign this values to your javascript variable, and populate the fields dynamically.